# Download a text file using Vue Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-vue

I am figuring out how I can download a text file on the client side using vuejs.
I have searched and all what I have done is to install Filesaver in laravel application
using npm install file-saver --save
I am also not sure how I will import it in my component or include it in the app.js file.
For the table am able to add a button for calling the function but this does not work.

```
 <a href="#" @click="SaveTextFile()"></a>
```

Method:

```
 function SaveTextFile() {
    let file = new Blob(['test'], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
    saveAs(blob, 'test.txt')
  }
```

Any idea how I can download or use a different approach in Vue Js

Comment: i guess you have to take a look on doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver#examples

Comment: @KamleshPaul my problem is registering as global component in app.js. Can you assist

Comment: just import in component and use it

Comment: does saveAs module is not working for you ? it's used to download created files on client you can also use plain js

Comment: @MohsinAmjad It is not working, the problem I have is that am using VUE JS and Laravel. I dont know the classes to import in the app.js. They have not shown in documentation

Comment: you have to import the module in vue component such as 
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver' and in methods define a function same as above and in template define your html this should work